# util.inspect.defaultOptions in TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript

In `node.d.ts` its declared as

```
declare module "util" {
    export function inspect(object: any, showHidden?: boolean, depth?: number | null, color?: boolean): string;
    export function inspect(object: any, options: InspectOptions): string;
}
```

so I cant extend it

I tried

```
declare module 'util' {
  export interface inspect {
    defaultOptions: InspectOptions;
  }
}
```

but it keeps erroring
`Property 'defaultOptions' does not exist on type '{ (object: any, showHidden?: boolean, depth?: number, color?: boolean): string; (object: any, opt...'.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `namespace` to extend function.

And it already fixed in @types/node